# Ansible. Looping over values extracted from output

Tags: string, loops, ansible

im quite new to Ansible and eager to learn how much it can do. I have a task to do the following:

1. Run command bpps -a to get a list of running NetBackup processes.
2. Go through each string of output (we're interested in strings having 'bpbrm -backup' in them)
3. Extract following data from those strings: Policy name (field after -cl key), Backup Schedule (field after -sched key), Hostname (field after -c key) ( I assume regex with capturing groups will do the trick? )
4. Put this data into data structure we can iterate over
5. Iterate over this data structure and run the bpbackup -i -p policy_name -s schedule_name -h hostname command to restart backup jobs for the client that were running backups at the time when we've collected data with bpps -a

I can do it with my eyes closed on Python, however i'd like to be able to do such tasks using Ansible alone to improve my skills if it takes sane amount of time and code :)

I would very appreciate if you will give some explanation on how it works, also could you please share some resources where i can find some Ansible tasks to practice on?

Its super easy for Python but I wasn't able to find some practice for Ansible yet. Thanks in advance and sorry for lame question :)

The output:

```
[root@media.server ~]# bpps -a
        NB Processes
        ------------
        root      8806     1  0 Sep30 ?        03:49:04 /usr/openv/pdde/pdag/bin/mtstrmd --config /usr/openv/lib/ost-plugins//mtstrm.conf
        root     11339     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:34:18 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/vnetd -proxy inbound_proxy -number 0
        root     11340     1  1 Sep30 ?        05:30:58 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/vnetd -proxy outbound_proxy -number 0
        root     11342     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:01:30 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/vnetd -proxy http_pbx_tunnel -number 0
        root     11431     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:01:37 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/vnetd -standalone
        root     11435     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:01:13 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/bpcd -standalone
        root     11543     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:02:43 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/nbdisco
        root     11674     1  0 01:18 ?        00:00:00 bpbrm -backup -S netbackup.master.server -c server1.domain.org -ct 13 -ru root -cl backup_policy-1 -sched Differential-File-6W -b server1.domain.org_1602890336 -bt 1602890336 -dt 109422 -st 1 -mediasvr media.server -jobid 11406453 -jobgrpid 11406420 -masterversion 812000 -maxfrag 51200 -bpstart_time 1602890636 -reqid -1601517467 -mt 0 -to 0 -stunit SS4-2_HEL_STU -rl 4 -rp 3628800 -eari 0 -p _PhysicalLSU -mst 6 -flags 0 -storagesvr storage_server-sts_type FTS -use_ofb -use_otm -WOFB_enabled 1 -nbu -jm -secure 1 -kl 28 -rg root -fso -tir -tir_plus -stream_count 5 -stream_number 5 -keyword NBUCS_3-4_6W_Hell-to-Ball -connect_options 16974338
        root     11678     1  0 01:19 ?        00:00:03 bpbrm -backup -S netbackup.master.server -c server2.domain.org -ct 13 -ru root -cl backup_policy-7 -sched Cumulative-File-6W -b server2.domain.org_1602890342 -bt 1602890342 -dt 1229040 -st 4 -mediasvr media.server -jobid 11406641 -jobgrpid 11406583 -masterversion 812000 -maxfrag 51200 -bpstart_time 1602890642 -reqid -1601517468 -mt 0 -to 0 -stunit SS4-2_HEL_STU -rl 4 -rp 3628800 -eari 0 -p _PhysicalLSU -mst 6 -flags 0 -storagesvr storage_server-sts_type FTS -use_ofb -use_otm -WOFB_enabled 1 -nbu -jm -secure 1 -kl 28 -rg root -fso -tir -tir_plus -stream_count 3 -stream_number 3 -keyword NBUCS_3-4_6W_Hell-to-Ball -connect_options 16974338
        root     11679 11674  2 01:19 ?        00:09:08 bptm -w -c server1.domain.org -dpath _PhysicalLSU -stunit SS4-2_HEL_STU -cl backup_policy-1 -bt 1602890336 -b server1.domain.org_1602890336 -st 1 -cj 1 -reqid -1601517467 -jm -brm -hostname server1.domain.org -ru root -rclnt server1.domain.org -rclnthostname server1.domain.org -rl 4 -rp 3628800 -sl Differential-File-6W -ct 13 -maxfrag 51200 -tir -eari 0 -mediasvr media.server -no_callback -connect_options 0x01010100 -auth_only -jobid 11406453 -jobgrpid 11406420 -masterversion 812000 -bpbrm_outsock_fd 4 -bpbrm_shm_id 667025419 -blks_per_buffer 512
        root     11696 11679  3 01:19 ?        00:15:00 bptm -w -c server1.domain.org -dpath _PhysicalLSU -stunit SS4-2_HEL_STU -cl backup_policy-1 -bt 1602890336 -b server1.domain.org_1602890336 -st 1 -cj 1 -reqid -1601517467 -jm -brm -hostname server1.domain.org -ru root -rclnt server1.domain.org -rclnthostname server1.domain.org -rl 4 -rp 3628800 -sl Differential-File-6W -ct 13 -maxfrag 51200 -tir -eari 0 -mediasvr media.server -no_callback -connect_options 0x01010100 -auth_only -jobid 11406453 -jobgrpid 11406420 -masterversion 812000 -bpbrm_outsock_fd 4 -bpbrm_shm_id 667025419 -blks_per_buffer 512
        root     11701 11678  1 01:19 ?        00:08:57 bptm -w -c server2.domain.org -dpath _PhysicalLSU -stunit SS4-2_HEL_STU -cl backup_policy-7 -bt 1602890342 -b server2.domain.org_1602890342 -st 4 -cj 1 -reqid -1601517468 -jm -brm -hostname server2.domain.org -ru root -rclnt server2.domain.org -rclnthostname server2.domain.org -rl 4 -rp 3628800 -sl Cumulative-File-6W -ct 13 -maxfrag 51200 -tir -eari 0 -mediasvr media.server -no_callback -connect_options 0x01010100 -auth_only -jobid 11406641 -jobgrpid 11406583 -masterversion 812000 -bpbrm_outsock_fd 4 -bpbrm_shm_id 667090957 -blks_per_buffer 512
        root     11718 11701  3 01:19 ?        00:15:36 bptm -w -c server2.domain.org -dpath _PhysicalLSU -stunit SS4-2_HEL_STU -cl backup_policy-7 -bt 1602890342 -b server2.domain.org_1602890342 -st 4 -cj 1 -reqid -1601517468 -jm -brm -hostname server2.domain.org -ru root -rclnt server2.domain.org -rclnthostname server2.domain.org -rl 4 -rp 3628800 -sl Cumulative-File-6W -ct 13 -maxfrag 51200 -tir -eari 0 -mediasvr media.server -no_callback -connect_options 0x01010100 -auth_only -jobid 11406641 -jobgrpid 11406583 -masterversion 812000 -bpbrm_outsock_fd 4 -bpbrm_shm_id 667090957 -blks_per_buffer 512
        root     11748     1  2 Sep30 ?        09:50:47 /usr/openv/pdde/pdcr/bin/spad
        root     11995     1 99 Sep30 ?        37-03:30:41 /usr/openv/pdde/pdcr/bin/spoold
        root     12036     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:05:50 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/nbrmms
        root     12109     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:59:19 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/nbsl
        root     12146     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:02:52 /usr/openv/netbackup/bin/nbsvcmon
        
        
        MM Processes
        ------------
        root     12015     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:01:50 /usr/openv/volmgr/bin/ltid
        root     12022     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:01:31 vmd
        root     12278 12015  0 Sep30 ?        00:00:00 tldd
        root     12356 12015  0 Sep30 ?        00:02:23 avrd
        root     12359     1  0 Sep30 ?        00:00:00 tldcd
```

Comment: Your question is at risk of closure because you have not provided any code you have tried, nor any error message you are getting from your attempt. This is not a "write code for me" website

Comment: Hey Daniel, i just want to know how Ansible could (if it could) create iterable data structures from strings using regexes. Right now i dont have any idea how to get close to solving this with it so that's the actual question. All data provided and the algorhytm are posted to make it clear. Im not asking for a fish I need a net.

Comment: @mdaniel, don't close it. A "net" provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"1) It's super easy for Python but I wasn't able to find some practice for Ansible yet. 2) I'm not asking for a fish I need a net."*

A: Let me provide you with the "net". In this case, the best option is [custom filter plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins). For example, the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - shell: 'df|grep snap/core'
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines
```

gives

```yaml
  result.stdout_lines:
  - /dev/loop3         99456    99456         0 100% /snap/core/9993
  - /dev/loop4         56704    56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
  - /dev/loop10        56320    56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
  - /dev/loop6        100096   100096         0 100% /snap/core/10126
```

Let's create a custom filter to parse the data. For example

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/parse_lines.py
def parse_lines(lines):
    array=[]
    for l in lines:
        array.append(l.split())
    return array

class FilterModule(object):

        def filters(self):
            return {
                'parse_lines': parse_lines
            }
```

Then the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines|parse_lines|to_yaml }}"
```

gives the lists with the parsed parameters

```yaml
  msg: |-
    - [/dev/loop3, '99456', '99456', '0', 100%, /snap/core/9993]
    - [/dev/loop4, '56704', '56704', '0', 100%, /snap/core18/1885]
    - [/dev/loop10, '56320', '56320', '0', 100%, /snap/core18/1880]
    - [/dev/loop6, '100096', '100096', '0', 100%, /snap/core/10126]
```

Comment: Wow, Vladimir this is really impressive. And we can make a Python based filters - just wow it provides so many possibilities - incredible. I really appreciate that. Won't you mind if ill get back to you when ill try to implement that by myself? I still need to get some things ordered in my head for the Ansible part of this  :))

Anyway please accept my deepest gratitude for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome. Open a new question if you have problems. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).